# who is scping your ssh server

Tags: ssh, scp

Just you can run `w` to find who is `ssh`ing into your server, how can you find out who is `scp`ing into an Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: I assumed the `w` and `who` worked for `scp` connections too but I've just tested it and it doesn't list them.

Comment: Why would you be scp-ing at all on your laptop?  If you have SSH enabled, you should be securing it with SSH key auth, and firewalling all other ports anyways...

Comment: @TheLordofTime since for some reasons we weren't able to make ssh server on both laptops so if on only one laptop a ssh server is establish we can transfer data in both direction only if we use scp

Comment: Close voter(s): Since Oli's edit, it's clear what this is asking,  and this should *not* be closed as NARQ.